# Angular: for switch vs dict lookup

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to decide which option to use for parsing through URL parameters, both appear to be suboptimal, it seems to me there has to be better way to deal with this - if there is, please suggest plausible Option #3. Assume up to 40 parameters.

Option #1

Cons: complexity O(n*k), where n is number of parameters, k is number of switch-cases; looks pretty bad as well

```
for(let param in params) {
  let value = params[param];
  switch(param){
    case 'param1': {
      doSomethingWithParam1(value);
      break;
    }
    case 'param2': {
      doSomethingWithParam2(value);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Option #2

Pros: complexity O(k)

Cons: looks even worse

```
let param = '';
param = 'param1';
if(param in params){
  let value = params[param];
  doSomethingWithParam1(value);
}
param = 'param2';
if(param in params){
  let value = params[param];
  doSomethingWithParam2(value);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript so you can create an object with functions and call them by key:

```js
let functions = {
    f1: function(){
        console.log(`it is f1 function`)
    },
    f2: function(){
        console.log(`it is f2 function`)
    },
    f3: function(){
        console.log(`it is f3 function`)
    }
}

let param = '';
param = 'f1';

console.log(functions[param]());
```